# my standard font type is kind of italic and it bothers me. how do i make it normal?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

so this is what my preamble looks like (i am just copying other people, that's how i learn so forgive the mess)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xfrac,bigints}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{enumerate}  


\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
\newcommand{\verteq}{\rotatebox{90}{$\,=$}}
\newcommand{\equalto}[2]{\underset{\scriptstyle\overset{\mkern4mu\verteq}{#2}}{#1}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt}}{0pt}
{\hspace*{.3\textwidth}\huge\bfseries}[\addvspace{-1pt}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt}}{0pt}
{\hspace*{.3\textwidth}\huge\bfseries}[\addvspace{-1pt}]


\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Sonuç}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Tanım}[section]
```

and this is what i write looks like
[image]

the italic look really bothers me. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The default style used by [`amsthm`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)'s `\newtheorem` is `plain`, which sets an `\itshape` (*italicised*) theorem body. You can use the `definition` style to remove this (or sets it using `\upshape`).

Here's the default:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\theoremstyle{definition}% Default is plain
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}
\chapter{A chapter}

\setcounter{section}{3}
\section{A section}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
\lipsum[1][3-4]
\end{corollary}

\begin{lemma}
\lipsum[1][5-6]
\end{lemma}

\begin{definition}
\lipsum[1][7-8]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Here's the same with `\theoremstyle{definition}` activated (uncommented):

[image]